# How Can We add a row every time on the top of the tableview first row on a button click in view?

Tags: iphone

Can you please help me to do this one?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [popOveritem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.05f]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[popimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"cellCOntent%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    UIView *cellbgColorView = [[[UIView alloc] init]autorelease];
    [cellbgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:40/255.0 green:128/255.0 blue:184/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellbgColorView;

    tableVIEW.scrollEnabled = NO;
    return cell;
```

first time the tableview will show one record and when i click to the button appeared in the view will add another row at the top of the table view?

Comment: Create a new project with master detail application template and observe.

Comment: [popOveritem addObject:obje atIndex:0];

Comment: Supose text is @"aaaaa";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the below code hope it gives you what you need

viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblTest;

    NSMutableArray *arrData;

    int increment;
}

-(IBAction)onClickAdd:(id)sender;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Data 1", nil];
    increment = 1;
}

-(IBAction)onClickAdd:(id)sender
{
    increment++;
    NSString *strInsertData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data %d",increment];
    [arrData insertObject:strInsertData atIndex:0];
    [tblTest reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arrData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @krishnabisht  yup its completely working i just saw your question and created this demo and tested it and it inserts new row everytime you tap on button add at the top of your tableview. if you implement this and found working please accept my answer and upvote me thanks :)